# Unable to create working subscription for Event Hub topic in Dapr

Tags: azure-eventhub, dapr

I have a Dapr application running locally, self-hosted with the Dapr cli. I've configured a Dapr `Component` and `Subscription` for subscribing to an Azure Event Hub, detailed below:

```yaml
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: eventhubs-pubsub
spec:
  type: pubsub.azure.eventhubs
  version: v1
  metadata:
  - name: connectionString
    value: "Endpoint=sb://[removed].servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=[removed];SharedAccessKey=[removed];EntityPath=myhub"
  - name: enableEntityManagement
    value: "false"
  - name: storageAccountName
    value: "[removed]"
  - name: storageAccountKey
    value: "[removed]"
  - name: storageContainerName
    value: "myapp"
scopes:
- myapp
```

```yaml
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Subscription
metadata:
  name: myhub-subscription
spec:
  topic: myhub
  route: /EventHubsInput
  pubsubname: eventhubs-pubsub
scopes:
- myapp
```

I've manually created a consumer group with the name of the Dapr app id - "myapp".

I've called the HTTP endpoint directly - a `POST` verb returning 200 - and it works fine. It also responds to `OPTIONS` verb.

The application starts succsesfully with no errors or warnings. I can see a logged message saying:

> INFO[0000] connectionString provided is specific to event hub "myhub". Publishing or subscribing to a topic that does not match this event hub will fail when attempted.  app_id=myapp instance=OldManWaterfall scope=dapr.contrib type=log ver=1.6.0

> INFO[0000] component loaded. name: eventhubs-pubsub, type: pubsub.azure.eventhubs/v1  app_id=myapp instance=OldManWaterfall scope=dapr.runtime type=log ver=1.6.0

No other message is logged regarding the pubsub and no message indicating a failure or success of the subscription itself. Nothing is created in the storgae container. If I remove the storage related config from the Component no failure is reported, despite those properties being mandatory. When I put a message on the Hub, unsurprisingly nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong? Everything I've read seems to indicate this set up should work.

Comment: I can't help with Dapr, but the error message leads me to believe that you're trying to access an Event Hub other than "myHub" - which is what your connection string is limited to.    You may want to try removing the ";EntityPath=myhub" token from the connection string.  That will match the namespace-level connection string and allow access to any Event Hub in that namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by exposing my app over http instead of https. Unfortunately there was no logging to indicate https was the issue, even with debug level switched on.